# htaccess rewrite regex issue wildcard

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This should be fairly easy for all regex gurus, however we are having issues with it.

I need a htaccess rewrite rule for following constellations...

```
"domain.tld/P123A123B123C123" -> points to index.php?pos=P123A123B123C123
```

or

```
"domain.tld/P1A2B3C4"  -> points to index.php?pos=P1A2B3C4
```

...the min length of numbers are 1 and max. length 3 (1-9)

note: a check for chars P A B C to exist on url is required.

Comment: `RewriteRule ([^/])+$ index.php?pos=$1` or `RewriteRule domain\.tld\/([^\/]+)$ index.php?pos=$1`

Comment: thx4help... but chars P A B C must exist on url...

Comment: `RewriteRule domain\.tld\/P\d{1,3}A\d{1,3}B\d{1,3}C\d{1,3}$ index.php?pos=$1`

Comment: this works..thx :-) RewriteRule  ^P\d{1,3}A\d{1,3}B\d{1,3}C\d{1,3}$ index.php?pos=$1 [L]

Comment: I've written this as an answer. You can hit the check mark next to my answer, to help me and future readers :)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this should work:

```
RewriteRule domain\.tld\/P\d{1,3}A\d{1,3}B\d{1,3}C\d{1,3}$ index.php?pos=$1
```